# linux ami nginx sites_enabled missing

Tags: linux, django, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

We are trying to install nginx on a Amazon Linux AMI to config uwsgi and django. But there is no sites-enabled dir under etc/nginx unlike on Ubuntu.

What am I missing here?

We are trying follow instructions from http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Comment: Would it be possible to provide the traceback of your nginx installation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Amazon Linux is based on RedHat/CentOS/Fedora so the default installation of nginx doesn't have a sites-avalable or a sites-enabled directory. (As opposed to Debian/Ubuntu) The directory where you usually put your configs is `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

Having said that, if you really want the sites-available/sites-enabled directories you can just run:

```
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-available
```

Then make sure the following is in the `http` section of your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
```

Then if you want to create a specific site configuration you can create your file 'whatever.conf' under /etc/nginx/sites-available . To enable it:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/whatever.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/whatever.conf
service nginx restart
```

Comment: instead of changing nginx.conf i did:  `echo 'include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;' | sudo tee /etc/nginx/conf.d/sites-enabled.conf`