# NGINX on AWS EC2 to forward HTTPS to HTTP://localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I have some dockers containers deployed on AWS EC2, that listens on `http`.
My idea is using `nginx` as reverse proxy, to pass traffic from `https`, to `http://localhost`.

Each container listens on a specific http port. The EC2 instance will accept traffic just on `http:80` and `http:443` and I will use subdomain to chose the right port.
So I should have:

```
https://backend.my_ec2instance.com --> http://localhost:4000
https://frontend.my_ec2instance.com --> http://localhost:5000
```

I'v got my free TSL certificate from Let's Encrypt (it's just on file containing public and private keys), and put it in

```
/etc/nginx/ssl/letsencrypt.pem
```

Then I have configured nginx in this way

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/custom.conf
```

and wrote

```
server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name backend.my_ec2instance;
       # Certificate
       ssl_certificate letsencrypt.pem;

       # Private Key
       ssl_certificate_key letsencrypt.pem;

       # Forward
       location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
               }
}
server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name frontend.my_ec2instance;
       # Certificate
       ssl_certificate letsencrypt.pem;

       # Private Key
       ssl_certificate_key letsencrypt.pem;

       # Forward
       location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
               }
}
```

then

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/custom.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enbled/
```

Anyway, if I open my browser on `https://backend.my_ec2instance` it's not reachable.
`http://localhost:80` instead correctly shows the nginx page.

Comment: You keep saying "redirect" but you are actually configuring traffic **forwarding** not redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS default port is port `443`. HTTP default port is port `80`. So this: `https://localhost:80` makes no sense. You are trying to use the HTTPS protocol on an HTTP port.

In either case, I don't understand why you are entering `localhost` in your web browser at all. You should be trying to open `https://frontend.my_ec2instance.com` in your web browser. The `locahost` address in your web browser would refer to your local laptop, not an EC2 server.

---

Per the discussion in the comments you also need to `include` your custom Nginx config in the base configuration file.

Comment: yes you'r right, and I misunderstood the way the config works. Let's use other ports, but I want to open outside just the 443. So I'd like to forward `https://[subdomain].my_ec2instance.com` to internal port `4000` or `5000`

Comment: It looks like you have it setup to do that already. What happens when you enter `https://[subdomain].my_ec2instance.com` in your web browser?

Comment: nothing, not reachable

Comment: Are trying to append subdomains to the EC2 instance DNS name? That isn't possible. You can't just invent subdomains without creating DNS records for them, and you don't control the AWS DNS records. You would need to point a custom domain name that you own at the EC2 instance.

Comment: I've already own a `domain.com` on another service. I've created a new `A` record `sub.domain.com` pointing to the IP of EC2

Comment: So if you enter `https://sub.domain.com` in your web browser, that gives you a "not reachable" error?

Comment: yes. I think the https is not working. port 443 is open

Comment: To be clear, `443` is open in the security group attached to the EC2 instance, correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: Is nginx actually running? Did you restart it after you made all the configuration changes? Does the configuration line `server_name frontend.my_ec2instance;` match the actual subdomain you are entering in the web browser? Does the EC2 instance have a public IP address?

Comment: yes for all the answers. localhost:80 shows the nginx web page. server_name is correct and the subdomain as well. maybe nginx is not taking my config file? How can I check which config file it's reading?

Comment: Checking the config file depends on the operating system you are using. What command do you use to start nginx? You could try `sudo systemctl config nginx`

Comment: I am on AWS Linux2 (the one similar to CentOS). I tried `sudo nginx -t` and it just shows `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. there is no mine `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: Did you create the `sites-enabled` directory? Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742578/13070

Comment: that answer solved my problem. Many thanks! it was about the missing `include` of my custom config file. If you write this as answer, I'll mark it as final answer. thank you

Comment: @DeLac I updated my answer to include that.